# Python/ Update value of variable threading and tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I encounter a problem that slows me down a lot in my development ..
Indeed, I can not update the Queue with the Threading module of python!
I have searched several sites, and I could not find fault that could prevent my variable from updating.

My tkinter button should allow me to run another python script. To do this, I use Threading so I can use the GUI without interrupting it.

***I explain my problem:***

My tkinter button should allow me to run another python script. To do this, I use Threading so I can use the GUI without it being interrupted. Another button should allow me to update the Queue, and this is what the action does not do.

My main script with Tkinter:

```
import Tkinter, cv2
from Tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
import threading, Queue
import pyautogui, os, time, urllib2, urlparse
import cv2
from yes2 import *

def print1():
    global kill, q
    kill = []
    q = Queue.Queue()
    q.put("True")
    thread = Thread(target = main, args=(kill, q))
    thread.start()
def stop():
    global q
    q.put("False")
    print q.get()



root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title('breakable')

bouton= Button(root, text="Run", command=print1)
bouton.grid(row=3, column=0)

bouton= Button(root, text="stop", command=stop)
bouton.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to open this other script:

```
def main(kill, q):

    while True:
        try:
            get = q.get(timeout=2)
            print get
        except Empty as error:
            print("Error too many times")
```

The value that comes out is "True", but when I click on my stop button, which is supposed to update my Queue in "False", well it does nothing

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does update your Queue, but on the very next line you `get` the value out again. Remove the `print q.get()` from the "stop" function.

Comment: Argh yes I am stupid :( Thank you very much I understand better my error now